# Contractible affine surfaces of log Kodaira dimension 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, gt.geometric-topology

The first examples of contractible smooth affine algebraic surfaces (over the complex numbers) of log Kodaira dimension 2 were constructed in a famous paper of Ramanujam

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970735?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

A much broader class of examples can be constructed using the algorithm of

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200784739

Question A: Is there a classification of contractible affine surfaces of log Kodaira dimension 2?

Question B: If not, are there explicit examples of such surfaces X and Y where it is not known whether X and Y are isomorphic?